# Simplifying multiple 'if's with rxjava

Tags: refactoring, rx-java

Which RxJava operations should I use to rewrite this mess to more simple version?

```
.map(content -> {
                    if (content.getPost() != null) {
                        return content.getPost();
                    } else if (content.getAction() != null) {
                        return content.getAction().getPost();
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
```

Something like

```
.map(Content::getPost)
.map(Content::getAction::getPost)
.combine( .. )
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't simplify that with RxJava; it looks fine as is btw.

Comment: Thanks! Although, there is always way to perfect lines (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much what akarnokd said except you can perhaps filter out the null post emissions using

```
 .filter(content -> (content.getPost() != null) || ((content.getAction() != null) && (content.getAction().getPost())))
 .map(content -> (content.getPost() != null ? content.getPost() : content.getAction().getPost()))
```